# I am new to python and I am getting a syntax error when using the print function, does anyone know why?

Tags: python, syntax

I am currently trying to learn some python basics and need to write a script that takes a list of student names, the number of missing assignments for each student and the current grade of the student.

Using this information, I want to create an automated email to send to each student. My code is below:

```
names = raw_input('Enter names separated by commas: ')
assignments = raw_input('Enter assignment counts separated by commas: ')
grades = raw_input('Enter grades separated by commas: ')

names_list = names.split(',')
assignments_list = assignments.split(',')
grades_list = grades.split(',')

message = "Hi {},\n\nThis is a reminder that you have {} assignments left to \
submit before you can graduate. You're current grade is {} and can increase \
to {} if you submit all assignments before the due date.\n\n"

for i in range(len(names)):
    potential_grade = int(grades_list[i]) + (2*int(assignments_list[i])
    print(message.format(names_list[i].title(), assignments_list[i], grades_list[i], potential_grade))
```

After executing this script I receive the following message:

```
File "testing.py", line 15
    print(message.format(names_list[i].title(), assignments_list[i], grades_list[i], potential_grade))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening, and what I need to do to rectify this problem?

Comment: You're missing a `)` on the line above the `print` line.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I didn't see that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close a statement before the print

```python
potential_grade = int(grades_list[i]) + (2*int(assignments_list[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your parantheses. You may be missing a ')'

Answer (score 0):

Add a closing bracket in the line above print.